# JIRA DC Scriptrunner - change the name of a custom field context

Tags: jira, scriptrunner-for-jira

JIRA Data Center v9.x

using Scriptrunner, I can get the context name of a custom field

```
CustomField cField = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject(customFieldId)
List<FieldConfigScheme> contexts = cField.getConfigurationSchemes() 
if ( contexts.size() == 1 ){
    FieldConfigScheme tmpContext = contexts[0]
    log.warn("tmpContext :: ${tmpContext.name}")
}
```

I need to be able to change the context name!
The FieldConfigScheme class does not have a set...

I have looked through all the related classes I can find, and done Google searches, all to no avail.

is there a way to change the custom field context name using Scriptrunner?

That did the trick
This is what I got working!

```
def allCFIDs = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObjects().collect({return it.getId()})
    allCFIDs.each { customFieldId ->
        CustomField cField = 
            customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject(customFieldId)
        List<FieldConfigScheme> contexts = cField.getConfigurationSchemes() 
        FieldConfigScheme tmpContext = contexts[0]
        if ( tmpContext.name.contains("Fred") ){
            def newname = tmpContext.name + " Flintstone"
            log.warn("Rename Context:: ${tmpContext.name}    to ::  ${newname}")
            def schemeData = new SchemeBuilder( tmpContext )
            schemeData.setName( newname )
            def updatedScheme = schemeData.toFieldConfigScheme()
            fieldConfigSchemeManager.updateFieldConfigScheme( updatedScheme )
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try `updateFieldConfigScheme(FieldConfigScheme newScheme, List<JiraContextNode> contexts, ConfigurableField field)` https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/7.0.2/com/atlassian/jira/issue/fields/config/FieldConfigScheme.html

Comment: As you got it running by yourself it is totally ok to write it down as an answer by your own and accept it as the correct one. It helps others to see that this question already is answered and can find the answer easier. ;)